# Value da data esta trocando mês pelo dia

Tags: php, data, formatação

```
<input type="text" id="inicio" class="cad-input" name='dataInicial' value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>"  style="width: 190px;"></> ,
```

a variável esta no formato `date('d/m/Y')` e esta trocando para `date('m/d/Y')`

http://ccmbr.com.br/ajaxDatas/

```
<?php 
$dias = $_POST['duration']; 
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial']; 
$dataFinal = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+$dias days",strtotime($dataInicial))); 
$dataInicial = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+0 days",strtotime($dataInicial))); 
echo '</br>'.'</br>'; 
echo "data inicial ".$dataInicial; 
echo '</br>'.'</br>'; 
echo "+ " .$dias." dias "; 
echo '</br>'.'</br>'; 
echo "data final ".$dataFinal. '</br>';
```

Comment: Seja mais claro quanto a sua dúvida. O que você precisa? O que você tentou fazer?

Comment: Ta normal, dia 10 + 7 = 17

Comment: onde está o script que calcula nova data?

Comment: <?php
$dias        = $_POST['duration'];
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial'];
$dataFinal   = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+$dias days",strtotime($dataInicial)));
$dataInicial = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+0 days",strtotime($dataInicial)));
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "data inicial ".$dataInicial;
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "+ " .$dias." dias  ";
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "data final ".$dataFinal. '</br>';

Comment: Se alguma resposta solucionou seu problema marque-a como `aceita` veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 3):

> Utiizando mktime() que é útil para a aritmética e validação de data.

1 - Salvamos a data enviada do formulário em uma variável `$dataInicial`;

```
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial'];
```

2 - Obtemos os componentes desta data com a função `list()`.

```
list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode('/', $dataInicial);
```

3 - De posse desses componentes acima, usaremos-los na função `mktime` para obtermos o `timestamp` (número de segundos decorrentes desde 01/01/1970) da data enviada já somando o numero de dias vindo do formulário (`$dia + $dias`) para posterior obtenção da data final.

```
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia + $dias, $ano);
```

4 - Aplicamos a função `strftime` para mostrar o timestamp no formato desejado

```
$dataFinal = strftime('%d/%m/%Y', $time);
```

**Código completo**

```
$dias        = $_POST['duration'];
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial'];


//obtendo os componentes da sua data.
list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode('/', $dataInicial);

//usando mktime para obter o timestamp desejado (somando o numero de dias)
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia + $dias, $ano);

//strftime para mostrar o timestamp em formato desejado
$dataFinal = strftime('%d/%m/%Y', $time);

echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "data inicial ".$dataInicial;
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "+ " .$dias." dias  ";
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "data final ".$dataFinal. '</br>';
```

**[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/wLZRkK)**

—  [**list()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php) é usada para criar uma lista de variáveis em apenas uma operação

—  [**mktime**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php) - obtém um timestamp Unix de uma data. Este timestamp é um inteiro longo contendo o número de segundos entre a Era Unix (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT), e o tempo especificado

—  [**strftime**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php) — Formata uma hora/data de acordo com as configurações locais

---

### Utilizando o método modify

```
$dias        = $_POST['duration'];
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial'];

// Criar o objeto representando a data
$obj_data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dataInicial);

// Definir a hora, minuto e segundo, que não foram informados
// (caso contrário, é obtido os valores da hora atual)
$obj_data->setTime(0, 0, 0);

// Realizar a soma de $dias dias
$obj_data->modify("+$dias days");

// Formatar a data obtida
echo $obj_data->format('d/m/Y');
```

[**Exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/YEtdkQ)

[**DateTime::createFromFormat**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php) - retorna um novo objeto DateTime formatado de acordo com um formato informado

[**setTime**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.settime.php) - redefine o horário atual do objeto DateTime para um diferente

[**modify**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.modify.php) - altera o timestamp de um objeto DateTime, incrementando-o ou decrementando-o

---

### Utilizando a classe DateInterval

```
$dias        = $_POST['duration'];
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial'];

// Criar o objeto representando a data
$obj_data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dataInicial);
$obj_data->setTime(0, 0, 0);

$intervalo = new DateInterval("P{$dias}D");
$obj_data->add($intervalo);

// Formatar a data obtida
echo $obj_data->format('d/m/Y');
```

[**Exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/1hAOLo)

[**DateInterval**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/dateinterval.construct.php) - cria um novo objeto DateInterval

[**add**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.add.php) - adiciona uma quantidade de dias, meses, anos, horas, minutos e segundos de um objeto DateTime

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dias        = $_POST['duration'];
$dataInicial = $_POST['dataInicial'];
$dataFinal   = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+$dias days",strtotime($dataInicial)));
$dataInicial = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+0 days",strtotime($dataInicial)));
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "data inicial ".$dataInicial;
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "+ " .$dias." dias  ";
echo '</br>'.'</br>';
echo "data final ".$dataFinal. '</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Ex.: 00/00/0000" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime(" +x days"));?>">
```

onde `x` vai ser sua variável do valor selecionado